# D3 Chart inside table (angular 2)

Tags: angular, d3.js, charts

I have a requirement to show a d3 bar chart inside a table . The table rows are dynamic and I use ngFor to create the rows dynamically. For some reason the chart is not getting displayed. Please take a look at the plunk.
https://plnkr.co/edit/IIfkLYS4iFlcj7d7SGlO?p=preview

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of itemsList">
            <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>
            <td><bar-chart [chartData]="item.cData"></bar-chart></td>
          </tr>
```

The bar chart above the table shows up fine. But the chart repeated in the table is the one not displaying.

I also checked that if I comment out the bar chart above the table, then the chart in the first row of the table gets displayed, but not the chart in the second row. 
Requesting your help in this ? Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always use the first element with class `chart`

```
const chart = d3.select('.chart')
```

To distinguish each chart i would do the following:

**bar-chart.component.html**

```
<svg class="chart" #chart></svg> // add #chart
```

**bar-chart.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('chart') chart: ElementRef;
...
const chart = d3.select(this.chart.nativeElement);
```

**[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jg7kOWxMWCY7F0tmhJ00?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks !! Worked like a charm